# How to prepend text to Img src value

Tags: javascript, opportunity, jquery

I have this code:

```
<td><apex:outputText value="{!e.p.Imagen_Producto__c}" escape="false"></apex:outputText></td>
```

where the value "{!e.p.Imagen_Producto__c}" is equivalent to

```
<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" alt="Foto" border="0"/>
```

Can I use JQuery to change the src value to

```
"/b2b/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="
```

Thanks

Comment: It is possible. However, is it possible for you to change the data source so that the `img` tag has the proper `src` value when the `Imagen_Producto__c` field is populated?

Answer (score 2):

Some rough jQuery to do this:

```
<td>
    <apex:outputText value="{!e.p.Imagen_Producto__c}" escape="false"></apex:outputText>
    <script>
        // retrieve the image element previous to this script element
        var imgTag = jQuery(document.currentScript).prev('img');

        // set the src attribute on the image element, prepended with "/b2b"
        jQuery(imgTag).attr('src', '/b2b' + imgTag.attr('src'));
    </script>
</td>
```

Comment: Great Thanks Mark! If I put all of the jQuery above in a function what would be the best way to call it? I don't believe apex:outputText supports the onload attribute.

Comment: No need for an `onload`, simply call it in an inline script block immediately after the element just as I did. What is your hesitation for not using the inline script tag?